# Adding multiple values to a dictionary based on a key

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a graph of all the destinations from a point a to b
For this i wrote the code

```
from sys import stdin
starting,ending=input().split()
startnodes=set()
flights=[]
for line in stdin:
    x,y,z=line.split()
    flights.append([x,y,int(z)])
    startnodes.add(x)
    startnodes.add(y)
graph={}

for i in startnodes:
    for j in flights:
        if i==j[0]:
            graph.update({i:{j[1]:j[2]}})
print(graph)
```

Input:

```
Bangalore Hyderabad
Bangalore Mangalore 50
Mangalore Hydrabad 40
Bangalore Hyderabad 10000
Bangalore Chennai 4000
Chennai Hyderabad 4000
```

Output:

```
{'Mangalore': {'Hydrabad': 40}, 'Bangalore': {'Chennai': 4000}, 'Chennai': {'Hyderabad': 4000}}
```

Expected Output

```
{'Mangalore': {'Hydrabad': 40}, 'Bangalore': {'Chennai': 4000,'Mangalore': 50}, 'Chennai': {'Hyderabad': 4000}}
```

The problem here is that i am expecting multiple Entries for the key 'Bangalore, but that isn't happening

Comment: `update()` only updates the outer dictionary by overwriting the value of a key with a new value for same key (and creating new keys). You have to check if the key exists already in outer dictionary and update the inner dictionary then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
graph.setdefault(i, {}).update({j[1]: j[2]})
```

instead of this:

```
graph.update({i: {j[1]: j[2]}})
```